# Cannot install Matlab 2016b to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab

Downloaded Matlab 2016b `.iso` files as `dvd1` and `dvd2`.

`Right Click` > `extract here`

Opened terminal and `cd  /path_of_dvd1` then typed `sudo ./install`

Such an error occured

> The installer cannot be run from inside the DVD directory. Change to
>   your home directory and execute this command:
>
> /home/username/Downloads/R2016b_glnxa64_dvd1/install

I did not understand what to do. How to fix it and install Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that you have to be currently located in your home folder, and then execute the install script to start the installation process.

To do that, just open terminal, and then execute the install script from there by using the full path to the install script.

```
./path/to/installscript
```

which can be

```
./home/<your username>/Downloads/R2016b_glnxa64_dvd1/install
```

Comment: Did it from home and result is
sudo: ./home/<username>/Downloads/R2016b_glnxa64_dvd1/install: command not found

Comment: worked when removed '.'